# Fitting lognormal distribution with MLE given a set of data

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, lognormal-distribution

I am given a set of data and need to find the MLE of it. I need to fit a log normal distribution of this data set.  [in R studio]

Comment: You don't compute the MLE of data, you compute MLE of parameters. Is it a two-parameter lognormal? What parameterization are you using? Do you need MLEs for all parameters or just some?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to obtain maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters of a two-parameter lognormal under the usual parameterization ($\mu, \sigma^2$ being the mean and variance of the distribution of the logs) is to take the natural log of the data, and obtain the maximum likelihood estimates on the log scale.

This is then the fairly trivial problem of obtaining MLE's of the corresponding parameters (i.e. the same $\mu,\sigma^2$) in the [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters).

This ability to transform and estimate on a more convenient "scale" is a very useful property of maximum likelihood estimators. See the second half of the section on functional invariance at the Wikipedia article on [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Functional_invariance) (the first half being about invariance to transformation of the parameter rather data). [If you only needed to transform forward rather than back again to the original scale as here, the requirement of a one-to-one transformation mentioned there would not be necessary.]

Note, however, that the usual Bessel-corrected sample variance is not maximum likelihood for the variance parameter in a normal.