# Fitting a sample streamflow data to log-normal distribution

Tags: distributions, python, fitting, lognormal-distribution

So I'm a beginner at python and I have a streamflow data for 132 months and I need to fit every months streamflow data to lognormal distribution and finally plot the original data and fitted data on the same graph. I searched all over the Internet including stackoverflow but I always came across with randomly generated lognormal distributions. What I need is first the data is converted into a distribution then fit into lognormal distribution.

Comment: When you say you have 132 months streamflow data, could you expand a bit on what it looks like? What numbers do you have for each month? Is it daily (or more frequent) measurements over the month, or a monthly total, or some other sort of summary?

Comment: Sorry for misrepresenting the data, the data is actually consist of 132 month which is 4018 days of streamflows (1st day: 20m^3/l; 2nd day 15m^3/l and so on). What I wanted to do is fit a lognormal curve to the all the 132 months and finally find 132 mean and stdev for each month)

Comment: The simplest reasonable parameters for the fitted lognormal distribution would be the mean and the standard deviation of the logs of your data. Then you can plot histograms of the original data and that fitted distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Your language indicates some misunderstandings. You have monthly streamflow data for 132 months, one value per month? That is one empirical distribution, and you fit one lognormal distribution to that. There should be no need to do anything to *convert it into a distribution*.

Then, the parameters of the lognormal, usually called the *logmean* and *logvariance*, is just the mean and variance of the normal distribution of the log of your values. See [Fitting lognormal distribution with MLE given a set of data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305502/fitting-lognormal-distribution-with-mle-given-a-set-of-data).

Comment: I don't think anything is usually called the logvariance. This is the first time that term appears on CrossValidated, and a Google search on the term turns up more uses in code than in English (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22logvariance%22) See my related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392189/good-terminology-for-the-parameters-of-a-lognormal-distribution